# Can we use ng-bootstrap in Angular 4 project?

Tags: angular, angular5, ng-bootstrap

In our front-end project, we are using Angular 4. And we would like to use ng-bootstrap library in our Angular 4 project. But [ng-bootstrap documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)  saying it's required Angular 5. We would not like to upgrade our project to Angular 5 but still willing to use ng-bootstrap. Can we do that? Someone already having experience with Angular 4 and ng-bootstrap? Any thoughts or advice highly appreciated.

Please note that: I'm not talking about [ngx-boostrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/)

Comment: You could install a beta version, for example `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5`. It worked with Angular 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant use it.

To use it we upgraded from angular 4 to 5, it wasnt painful as excepted. The only problem we had was updating some external component who changed their interface in the update from 4 to 5.

Comment: Thanks @gmazzotti for sharing your experiences with this issue. I just upgraded my project with Angular 5 painlessly :)

Answer (score 0):

in thier [docs](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap) it says:

"Additionally you can find demos and docs deployed from latest code with angular v4 and angular v5"

i guess that means: yes you can

Comment: I'm not talking about ngx-bootstrap (https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap) you sent the link. But I'm talking about ng-boostrap (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io). Please read my post care-fully again. Thanks

Comment: sorry, looked now at ng-bootstrap.github.io, in CHANGEGLOG 1.0.0-alpha.25 it says:"bump up Angular dependency to 4.0.3", so that mean: they support angular4 at least at this version

Comment: 1.0.0-beta.7 (2017-12-08)
This release bumps up minimal Angular dependency to 5.0.2.