# Ng-bootstrap with angular 4 not showing tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap 3.0.0 with angular 4 to show the bootstrap tooltip on hover over a icon. But for unknown reasons, the tooltip doesnt show up on hover of the icon. 
This is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-left:20px;" placement="bottom" ngbTooltip="Import">
    <input type="file" id="fileLoader" name="files" style="display:none" accept=".csv" (change)="uploadFileToDataManager($event)"
     multiple/>
    <div id="btnUpload" class="import-icon" tabindex="0" role="button">
        <div style="margin-top:5px">
            <span style="float:left;" class="importIconFont icon-cloud-import"></span>
            <!--<a class="exportIconFont icon-cloud-export"></a>-->
            <!--<span style="color:#263a47;font-family:ev;margin-left: 10px;">Upload</span>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have included the module in app.module :

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: here https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started are the minimal versions dependencies...if you are using -v3.0 then you have to use angular -v6.0

Comment: @AniketAvhad So does this mean i cannot use this with Angular 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use ng-bootstrap for angular 4 project [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622009/can-we-use-ng-bootstrap-in-angular-4-project).

But, you can use ngx-bootstrap by installing it from `npm install ngx-bootstrap@next` and integrating the ngx-bootstrap tooltip from taking reference from [ngx-bootstrap tooltip](https://ngx-universal.herokuapp.com/tooltip)

The ngx-bootstrap support is added with a @next version of ngx-bootstrap([see the support here](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1902))

For closing the tooltip after 2 seconds, add two custom functions in .ts as

```
PopoverEnabled() {
      this.stopPopover();
}

stopPopover() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        pop.hide();
    }, 2000);
}
```

and use in html , in which div you have the tooltip code as

```
<div (mouseenter)="PopoverEnabled()" (mouseleave)="stopPopover()"></div>
```

Comment: How can i hide the tooltip after 2 seconds?

Comment: you want to show the tooltip on mouse-enter and want the tooltip to hide after 2 seconds?  Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes thats right. It should hide after 2 seconds as well as hide when i move the mouse away from the icon

Comment: I have updated my answer as per your requirement, please let me know if the functionality is working or it need some more research.

Comment: But pop in pop.hide would be undefined in the .ts file right? How do i pass the reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178614/discussion-between-blizzard-and-ui-dev).